# Does unobstructedness depend on the representative of a Kodaira-Spencer class?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. One says that a Kodaira-Spencer class $c \in H^1(X, TX)$ is *unobstructed* if there exist $\phi_n \in \Omega_X^{0,1}(T^{1,0}X)$ for $n \ge 1$ such that $c = [\phi_1]$ and $\phi(t) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi_nt^n$ converges to a solution to the Maurer-Cartan equation
$$\bar{\partial}\phi(t) + [\phi(t), \phi(t)] = 0$$
for $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
This defines a deformation of complex structures $I_t$, where the $(0, 1)$-part of $I_t$ is $(1+\phi(t))(T^{0, 1}X)$.

**Question.** Suppose that $c \in H^1(X, TX)$ is unobstructed. Can we solve the Maurer-Cartan equation starting with *any* representative $\phi_1$ of $c$?

Comment: Don’t any two choices differ by $\partial$ of a holomorphic section of the holomorphic tangent bundle?  Since holomorphic sections of the holomorphic tangent bundle “integrate” to one-parameter families of biholomorphisms, I think you can always modify one extendable representative to any other choice of $\phi$.